# What is the difference between "博览会", "交易会" and "展销会"?

Tags: word-choice, difference, word

I know there are 3 phrases used to describe exhibition/fair, namely "博览会", "交易会" and "展销会". Can those phrases be used interchangeably or is there any difference for each specific phrase?

Answer (score 2):

博览会, 交易会 and 展销会 can be used interchangeablely. All of them mean "exhibition". They are synonyms, different only in literal meanings.

The literal meanings are:

> 博览会 broad viewing party
>
> 交易会 trade party
>
> 展销会 display and sales party